# How to determine if connection error is due to test or host machine

Tags: jmeter

I have come across a situation where I can`t decide what scenario would be best. I have written my test in JMeter as follows:
I have one test plan that runs test in **consecutive**.

I have 4 thread groups and each thread group has the following properties:

No of threads:  8000

Ramp-up period: 60 sec
Loop count : 10
Same user on each iteration: true

I was having connection error, connection time out error.

So, to make it work , when I test from localhost (same machine), I have to enter a response time out of 1800000 ms, whereas when I do the same test on a remote server, I have to enter the response time out of 3600000 ms.

Can someone please advise :

1. Is it a good idea to include response time?  Is there any other issue I should look for instead of including a response time?  Is it an alert for other issue?
2. Can I improve the test without using response time?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a couple of questions to you:

1. Do you really think that the real user will really wait for 1 hour for getting the response from the application?
2. How did you come to this 8000 users?

---

Now recommendations:

1. Never have JMeter and the system under test on the same machine, they are both resource intensive and they will start struggling for CPU cycles, memory pages, etc. and you won't be able to tell whether JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough or your application cannot respond properly
2. Follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Although the number of virtual users you can simulate with JMeter is very high it's limited by the machine/operating system resources so make sure JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO. The metrics can be checked using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). Once you notice that any of monitored metrics start exceeding i.e. 80% of total available capacity - mention how many users are online and this is how many you can simulate from this machine for this test. If you need more - go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)
4. The same for the system under test, if you hit the resources consumption limits you need either to upgrade the hardware or to deploy your application in clustered mode (if it supports such a mode)

Comment: I have started testing with 100 users and slowly increased the number of users until I reached 8000.  It was only starting with 8000 users that I started getting errors.  The app under test is on a different machine from that of JMeter. Both the JMeter machine and app machine, are 20 vcpus, 80 GiB memory virtual machines on azure.  None of them have hit 100 % cpu nor 100% memory.  We just can`t figure out a way to find out what is throttling.  Do we have a plugin that can test IIS performance or dot net performance.  The only hint we have is the connection time out.